# How to get team text and score using Beautiful soup with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get all the team vs team information and the score which is hidden under a show button using this url http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/7397-natus-vincere/matches. Im trying to get opp 1 vs opp 2 and the outcome of the game.. This is what I have so far for this problem.

```
def all_match_outcomes():

    for match_outcomes in all_match_history_url():
        page = requests.get(match_outcomes).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        for match_outcome in soup.select_one('div table.simple.gamelist.profilelist td'):
            opp_1 = match_outcome.select_one('a').find('span')
            print(opp_1)
```

Comment: Please show what code you have so far and what is not working.

Comment: Is it clear enough or should I add all the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The game results are under the hidden span (well, there is no "hidden" for `BeautifulSoup`, it is not a browser). The home score is in the `span` with `hscore` class, the away - in the `span` with `ascore` class. The team names are under inner `span` elements inside `span` elements with `opp1` and `opp2` classes. Implementation:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


match_outcomes = "http://www.gosugamers.net/counterstrike/teams/7397-natus-vincere/matches"
page = requests.get(match_outcomes).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.select('table.simple.gamelist.profilelist tr'):
    opp1 = row.find("span", class_="opp1").span.get_text()
    opp2 = row.find("span", class_="opp2")("span")[-1].get_text()

    opp1_score = row.find("span", class_="hscore").get_text()
    opp2_score = row.find("span", class_="ascore").get_text()

    print("%s %s:%s %s" % (opp1, opp1_score, opp2_score, opp2))
```

Prints:

```
Virtus.Pro.CS 2:1 Natus Vincere
Dobry&Gaming; 0:2 Natus Vincere
GODSENT 0:2 Natus Vincere
HellRaisers 0:2 Natus Vincere
Flipsid3 Tactics 1:2 Natus Vincere
Natus Vincere 1:2 Dobry&Gaming;
mousesports.CS 1:0 Natus Vincere
mousesports.CS 0:1 Natus Vincere
...
Natus Vincere 2:1 Flipsid3 Tactics
Team Dignitas.CS 0:1 Natus Vincere
```

Comment: I'm also trying to display both team names as well, there are 2 span tags and the team text is in the second span. How would I get the team names ?

Comment: @DJRodrigue it's already there in the answer, updated it 10 minutes ago to get the team names as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't refresh. Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

View the source of the page and you will see that all the info that you need is in a table with the class `simple gamelist profilelist`.

Read the 
[Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)
 and especially the find method.

Try to find patterns in the html source and you will quickly figure out how to iterate over each table data (`<td>`) and how to extract teams etc.